# Solving Sudoku program

Tags: java, loops, sudoku

I have a problem here. I am not getting perfect output. The following is my code that I wrote to prepare Sudoku. Even I know the reason for it, as it is unable to create any new unique number, it is printing the default value that is 0.I know I'm missing something that I can't think of. Can anyone suggest a solution for it? Thanks in advance.

```
public class FinalSudoku 
{
    int a[][]=new int[9][9];
    public void initialize1()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
         for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
        {
             a[i][j]=0;
        }

     }
    }
    protected boolean detectRow( int row, int num )
       {
          for( int col = 0; col < 9; col++ )
             if( a[row][col] == num )
                return false;

          return true ;
       }

    protected boolean detectCol( int col, int num )
       {
          for( int row = 0; row < 9; row++ )
             if( a[row][col] == num )
                return false ;

          return true ;
       }

    protected boolean detectBox( int row, int col, int num )
       {
          row = (row / 3) * 3 ;
          col = (col / 3) * 3 ;

          for( int r = 0; r < 3; r++ )
             for( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
             if( a[row+r][col+c] == num )
                return false ;

          return true ;
       }

    public void solve( int row, int col ) throws Exception
    {
        if( row > 8 )
             throw new Exception( "Solution found" ) ;

        if( a[row][col] != 0 )
             next( row, col ) ;
          else
          {
    for( int num = 1; num < 10; num++ )
    {
       if(detectRow(row,num) && detectCol(col,num) && detectBox(row,col,num) )
       {
          a[row][col] = num ;
          next(row, col) ;
       }
    }
          }
    }
    public void display()
    { 
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(a[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void next( int row, int col ) throws Exception
       {
          if( col < 8 )
             solve( row, col + 1 ) ;
          else
             solve( row + 1, 0 ) ;
       }  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        FinalSudoku fs = new FinalSudoku();
        fs.initialize1();

        fs.solve(0,0);

        fs.display();
    }

}
```

Output of this code:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
4 5 6 7 8 9 3 2 1
7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6
2 1 4 3 6 5 8 9 7
3 6 7 2 9 8 1 4 5
5 9 8 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: @AndyRay: What is wrong with `row = (row / 3) * 3`?

Comment: Solving sudoku is a really complex problem. Generating a problem is even more so. It seems you are a novice programmer and you likely don't have the necessary math skills to solve either of these problems. So, instead, why don't you create a sudoku solution verifier. That is, write a program that, given a 9x9 grid of numbers, check that they follow the rules of sudoku.

Comment: Also, exceptions are used for exceptional behavior. Finding a solution when the goal is to find a solution is not exceptional behavior.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux it's exactly the same as saying `row = row` ... `(x / 3) * 3 === x`. kind of scary that you got upvoted :(

Comment: @AndyRay: No, Andy, not at all... He is performing integer division, which means that you lose that fractional part of the division: `7 / 3 == 2`. Then multiply it again by three gives `6`. This method is used to round down to the lowest cell of a box in the grid. After performing `(x / 3) * 3`, the values `0,1,2` give as result `0`. Values `3,4,5` give `3` and values `6,7,8` give `6`.

Comment: @AndyRay Except that row is an integer and `4/3 * 3 = 1 * 3 = 3 != 4`.

Comment: @AndyRay, if you think my code is a nightmare, who asked you to comment. Just consider that it's not your business if you want to escape answering. It really hurts when someone chides other's hardwork. Of course you need not appreciate, at least you be silent. Even I myself accepted that there is fault in my code, that's the reason I posted this. I don't know why this site mentions that many restrictions while posting questions and don't care about these kind of unnecessary responses from some kind of people.

Answer (score 6):

You're not writing a solver, but a generator. You're problem is that you fill in values, without really checking if they will block the puzzle. Look at the place where your algo stopped.

```
1 2 3  4 5 6  7 8 9
4 5 6  7 8 9  3 2 1
7 8 9  1 2 3  4 5 6

2 1 4  3 6 5  8 9 7
3 6 7  2 9 8  1 4 5
5 9 8  0 0 0  0 0 0 < This row contains 5 and 8, 9

0 0 0  0 0 0  0 0 0
0 0 0  0 0 0  0 0 0
0 0 0  0 0 0  0 0 0
       ^
 This column contains 1,2,3,4 and 7

 And the center box, contains 6
```

So all numbers are taken for that place.

---

Take a look here: [Wiki: Sudoku algorithms: Blank Sudoku grids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku_algorithms#Blank_Sudoku_grids)
This code produces a filled grid, maybe that is interesting to start with?

---

Thanks to Alex D, for his good point:

In cases where you do really want to use a brute force algorithm like you are trying to do, you need to make it back up and try a different solution when it reaches a point where it can't succeed. If it backs all the way up to the beginning, with no choices left to try, then there is no solution. There are a few standard ways to implement such a "recursive search with backtracking".

This solving algorithm will work, but it will require some knowledge of recursion.

Comment: In cases where you do really want to use a brute force algorithm like the OP is trying to do, you need to make it back up and try a different solution when it reaches a point where it can't succeed. If it backs all the way up to the beginning, with no choices left to try, then there is no solution. There are a few standard ways to implement such a "recursive search with backtracking". @MartinCourteaux, perhaps you want to add some of this information to your answer? If so, I will delete this comment.

Comment: Thanks for your response Martijn. I know the reason for getting blocked and I mentioned in my question. But the thing is I am asking for help whether there is any technique to validate back the filled numbers and arrange those numbers in such a way that the current number gets a value.

Answer (score 0):

This Code Check the Sudoku.If it is correct then check_sudoku() method return true if it wrong then shows the row and column number which has a duplicate element.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array[][]={{9,6,3,1,7,4,2,5,8},
                   {1,7,8,3,2,5,6,4,9},
                   {2,5,4,6,8,9,7,3,1},
                   {8,2,1,4,3,7,5,9,6},
                   {4,9,6,8,5,2,3,1,7},
                   {7,3,5,9,6,1,8,2,4},
                   {5,8,9,7,1,3,4,6,2},
                   {3,1,7,2,4,6,9,8,5},
                   {6,4,2,5,9,8,1,7,3}};

    Sudoku sudoku=new Sudoku();
    if(sudoku.check_sudoku(array))
    {
        System.out.println("You won the game :)");
    }


}


public class Sudoku {

private int temp1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, temp2[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
private int data1, data2;

public boolean check_sudoku(int array[][]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            data1 = array[i][j];
            data2 = array[j][i];
            if (data1 >= 10 || data2 >=10 || data1 <= 0 || data2 <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Solution because value must be in between 1 to 9");
                return false;
            } else if (temp1[data1 - 1] == 0 || temp2[data2 - 1] == 0) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Solution please check " + (i + 1) + " row " + (j + 1) + " column or " + (j + 1) + " row " + (i + 1) + " column");
                return false;
            } else {
                temp1[data1 - 1] = 0;
                temp2[data2 - 1] = 0;
            }
        }
        int check1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
        int check2[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
        temp1 = check1;
        temp2 = check2;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}